# Convert implicit def to scala 3 given syntax

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3, cats-effect

For the following Random UUID generator using cats effect:

```scala
import java.util.UUID
import cats.effect.Sync
import cats.ApplicativeThrow

trait UuidGen[F[_]]:
  def make: F[UUID]
  def read(string: String): F[UUID]

object UuidGen:
  def apply[F[_]: UuidGen]: UuidGen[F] = implicitly

  implicit def forSync[F[_]: Sync]: UuidGen[F] =
    new UuidGen[F]:
      def make: F[UUID] = 
        Sync[F].delay(UUID.randomUUID)
      def read(string: String): F[UUID] =
        ApplicativeThrow[F].catchNonFatal(UUID.fromString(string))
```

What is the equivalent of `implicit def` in scala 3 `given` syntax?

Comment: What have you tried by yourself? Encountered errors?

Comment: The official documentation should help you straightforward: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html

Comment: Something like: `given RandomUuid[F](using F: Sync[F]) with` and in the next line `def make: F[UUID] = F.delay(UUID.randomUUID)`

Comment: Thank you. I have posted my implementation as answer. Unfortunately, the scala-lang.org was offline yesterday. https://github.com/scala/scala-lang/issues/1309

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import java.util.UUID
import cats.effect.Sync
import cats.ApplicativeThrow

trait UuidGen[F[_]]:
  def make: F[UUID]
  def read(string: String): F[UUID]

object UuidGen:
  def apply[F[_]: UuidGen]: UuidGen[F] = summon

  given [F[_]: Sync]: UuidGen[F] with
    def make: F[UUID] =
      Sync[F].delay(UUID.randomUUID)
    def read(string: String): F[UUID] =
      ApplicativeThrow[F].catchNonFatal(UUID.fromString(string))
```

Comment: Context syntax should be deprecated.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't understand your comment, could you please point out more specifically, what exactly should be deprecated?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin the `F[_]: Sync` syntax, I personally think that as of **Scala 3** is better to just use anonymous usings like `(using Sync[F])` - But again, that is just a personal opinion; that is why the _"should"_.